# R Studio crashes when using system(some-http-command) - anybody know a fix?

Tags: r, http, system, rstudio

Whenever I use any sort of HTTP command via the system() function in R studio, the rainbow circle of death appears and I have to force-quit R Studio. Up until now, I've written a bunch of checks to make sure a user isn't in R Studio before using an HTTP command (which I use a ton to access data), but it's quite a pain, and it would be fantastic to get to the root of the problem.

e.g.

```
system("http get http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M")
```

causes R studio to crash. Oddly, on another laptop of mine, such commands don't crash R Studio but cause the following error: 'sh: http: command not found', even though http is installed and works fine when using the terminal.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem / why it happens / does it occur for you guys too? Although I know a lot about R, I'm afraid I have no idea how to try to fix this problem.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is an "HTTP command" exactly? `system("http://www.google.com")`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear :) Any sort of HHTP get, put, etc. command. e.g. 
    system("http get http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M > us-bls.json")  will cause R studio to crash. On another computer, R studio doesn't crash, but outputs 'sh: http: command not found', even though http is installed in terminal and works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `http` from the `httpie` package on Linux hangs RStudio (and not plain terminal R) on my Linux system (your rainbow circle implies its a Mac?) so I'm getting the same behaviour as you.

Installing and using `wget` works for me:

```
system("wget -O /tmp/data.out http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M")
```

Or you could try R's native `download.file` function. There's a whole bunch of other functions for getting stuff off the web - see the Web Task View http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html

I've not seen this `http` command used much, so maybe its flakey. Or **maybe its opening `stdin`**...

Yes... Try this:

```
system("http get  http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M >/tmp/data2.out </dev/null" )
```

I think `http` is opening `stdin`, the Unix standard input channel, `RStudio` isn't sending anything to it. So it waits. If you explicitly assign `http`'s `stdin` as `/dev/null` then http completes. This works for me in `RStudio`.

However, I still prefer `wget` or `curl`-based solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Without more contextual information regarding Rstudio version / operating system it is hard to do more than suggest an alternative approach that avoids the use `system()`

Instead you could use `RCurl` and `getURL`

```
library(RCurl)
 getURL('http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M')
#[1] "{\"status\":\"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED\",\"responseTime\":129,\"message\":[],\"Results\":{\n\"series\":\n[{\"seriesID\":\"CXUALCBEVGLB0101M\",\"data\":[{\"year\":\"2013\",\"period\":\"A01\",\"periodName\":\"Annual\",\"value\":\"445\",\"footnotes\":[{}]},{\"year\":\"2012\",\"period\":\"A01\",\"periodName\":\"Annual\",\"value\":\"451\",\"footnotes\":[{}]},{\"year\":\"2011\",\"period\":\"A01\",\"periodName\":\"Annual\",\"value\":\"456\",\"footnotes\":[{}]}]}]\n}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `PUT`, `GET`, `POST`, etc directly in R, abstracted from `RCurl` by the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)

tmp <- GET("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CXUALCBEVGLB0101M")
dat <- content(tmp, as="parsed")
str(dat)

## List of 4
##  $ status      : chr "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED"
##  $ responseTime: num 27
##  $ message     : list()
##  $ Results     :List of 1
##   ..$ series:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
##   .. ..$ seriesID: chr "CXUALCBEVGLB0101M"
##   .. ..$ data    :List of 1
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  5 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ year      : chr [1:3] "2013" "2012" "2011"
##   .. .. .. ..$ period    : chr [1:3] "A01" "A01" "A01"
##   .. .. .. ..$ periodName: chr [1:3] "Annual" "Annual" "Annual"
##   .. .. .. ..$ value     : chr [1:3] "445" "451" "456"
##   .. .. .. ..$ footnotes :List of 3
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  0 variables
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  0 variables
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  0 variables
```